# how to create an array of hashes by looping over array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following array of hash. I am trying to loop over it and build an array of hash of values of id and product_order_id.

```
objects = 
[
  #<Product: 0x00007ffd4a561108
  @id="1",
  @product_id="2",
  @product_order_id="23",
  @description="abc",
  @status="abcde",
  @start_date=nil,
  @end_date=nil>,
  #<Product: 0x00007ffd4a560c80
  @id="45",
  @product_id="22",
  @product_order_id="87",
  @description="ahef",
  @status="gesff",
  @start_date=nil,
  @end_date=nil>
......more objects.....
    ]
```

This is what it should look like

```
[{ "1": "23" }, { "45": "87" }] -->its going to be uuid
```

I tried doing this but no luck

```
def mapped_product(objects)
    mapping = []
    objects.each do |object|
      mapping << {
        object.product_order_id: object.id
      }
    end
end
```

Any idea?

Comment: Don't you mean it should look like `[{ 1=>23 }, { 45=>87 }]`, as symbol names cannot begin with a digit?

Comment: What you expect is invalid.

Comment: A quick question, why do you want an array containing hashes that have only one key/value pair? It seems to me that `{ '1' => '23', '45' => '87' }` (one hash without wrapped array) is a better result.

Comment: The array of hash is not going to be just have 2 values, it could have 100 or 500 objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
def mapped_product(objects)
    mapping = []
    objects.each do |object|
      mapping << {
        object.id => object.product_order_id # I'm using an `=>` here
      }
    end
    mapping # return the new mapping
end
```

I've just changed the `:` on the hash for a `=>` to "make it dynamic" and swapped the values of `id` and `product_order_id`

You can also use a `map` here:

```
def mapped_product(objects)
    objects.map do |object|
     {  object.id => object.product_order_id }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

inline solution:

```
> Hash[objects.map{|p| [p.id, p.product_order_id] }]
# Output : [{ 1=>23 }, { 45=>87 }]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd usually implement it using an `each_with_object`

```
objects.each_with_object({}) { |obj, acc| acc[obj.id] = obj.product_order_id }
```

Unless I reaaaly want to squeeze some performance, than I'd go with [Gagan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53607013/202613)